# can't add to database through Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database

when the submit button is clicked the id of the selected medal should be returned and inserted in a database via Ajax. But this doesn't seem to work. Does someone know what's going on or what i've done wrong? 
This is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php

            while($medal = $allMedals->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "<img src='" . $medal['imagepath'] . "' />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='radio' class='selectmedal' value='" . $medal['medalid'] . "' />";
                }

?>
            <input type='submit' value='Nominate' id='submitknop' onclick='geklikt()'/>
</form>
```

And this is the function geklikt:

```
function geklikt(){
        alert($("#selectmedal").val());
        var medalid = $(".selectmedal").val();
        var data = { selectmedal:medalid };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/medal_save.php",
            data: data
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $(".feedback").text(msg.message);
        });

        return false;
```

The alert is being shown but shows the same id with every medal that is selected (id 3). This is the code from the medal_save.php:

```
<?php
    include('../classes/Nomination.class.php');

    if(!empty($_POST['selectmedal']))
    {
        $nomination = new Nomination();
        $nomination->Medal = $_POST['selectmedal'];
        try
        {
            $nominate->Save();
            $feedback ['message'] = "Nomination succes!";
            $feedback ['status'] = "success";
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $feedback ['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            $feedback ['status'] = "error"; 
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        $feedback ['message'] = "Please select a medal";
        $feedback ['status'] = "error";     
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($feedback);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The alert() is being shown? And what is the code of medal_save.php?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried debugging using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools?

Comment: You should do some more research and revise your question. It's never proper to say you can't interact with a database through Ajax, because the javascript code never directly interacts with the DB. Try doing some troubleshooting in your php script to see if you're getting what you expect from javascript. If you are, you know the problem is in your PHP script. The beauty of having an architecture that is in pieces is that you can troubleshoot the pieces.

Comment: The alert is being shown but shows the same value with every medal. I've edited the question to show you the code

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to get the **selected** radiobutton

```
 $('input[name=radioinputname]:checked', '#yourformid').val();
```

that is if you are not actually saying you want the attribute id ( ?)
if so use

```
 $('input[name=radioinputname]:checked', '#yourformid').attr("id");
```

so

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myradioform">
   <?php

        while($medal = $allMedals->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo "<img src='" . $medal['imagepath'] . "' />";
                echo "<input type='radio' name='radioinputname' 
                      class='selectmedal' value='" . $medal['medalid'] . "' />";
            }

      ?>
        <input type='submit' 
         value='Nominate' id='submitknop' onclick='geklikt()'/>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function geklikt(){
    alert($("#selectmedal").val());

    /* here */
    var medalid = $('input[name=radioinputname]:checked', '#myradioform').val();

   /* or if you actually meant to you want the attribute id */
   /*
  var medalid =  $('input[name=radioinputname]:checked', '#myradioform').attr("id");
 */

    var data = { selectmedal:medalid };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/medal_save.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $(".feedback").text(msg.message);
    });

    return false;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. It still gives id 3 for every one of the medals

Comment: can you edit the answer to include the output html from the php while loop?